# How to add an anchor to navigate within same page in ploty dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How to add an anchor to navigate within the same page in ploty dash?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to place an anchor using href to where you want to navigate. You can use html.A to add an invisible anchor.
Note that there's no '#' in html.A id.

Ex:

```
html.A(id="PageSection1"),
```

Then just place navigate button where you need it. Clicking the button will take you to the anchor position.

```
html.A(html.Button('Go to page section1', id='page1-btn', n_clicks=0),href='#PageSection1'),
```